# Psycopg2: psycopg2.connect() in Python has no result

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, python-2.6

I want to connect to a PostgreSQL database in python with Psycopg2, but when I run the connecting command, I get no results and no errors, and I can't get what's the problem.

Here is what I have in my terminal:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 26 2010, 22:31:48) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import psycopg2
>>> conn = psycopg2.connect("host=192.20.0.4 port=5432 user=mary
password=123456 dbname=reports")
```

It stops in this step, it doesn't go to the next line so that I can run any other commands, and doesn't print any errors or results, what should I do? what is the problem?

Comment: try this:`conn = psycopg2.connect(host="192.20.0.4" ,port=5432, user="mary",
password="123456", dbname="reports", database = "postgres_db")`

Comment: Can you connect successfully with psql and those settings alone?
Perhaps postgres is not configured to listen on that port, so you get stuck waiting for a connection that cannot ever be established.

Comment: @Alberto Yes I can connect to psql from other servers, and when I run telnet 192.20.0.4 5432  on this server, it connects successfully, the psycopg2 also worked some days ago, but it's not having any results now!

Comment: @katoozi Tried it but didn't work!

Comment: That's strange, what if you use another python version? I'm noticing you're using python2.6 which is no longer mantained and is over 10 years old. There might be some bug in the lib when using that old version. (highly unlikely but probably worth a shot)

Comment: @Alberto Unfortunately I can't change the version because there are some applications that need that version of python!

Comment: Double check postgresql.conf to ensure PostgreSQL itself is accepting connections from your source server.